# Python can't access subclass methods that aren't extended from base class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, instance, subclass

So I have in one module a subclass that is extended from a base class in another module.

The subclass extends a couple methods from the base class, but also includes several classes that are not extended

Now from a different module, I import the subclass, and for some reason, I only have access to the methods that are extended from the base class. If I try to call one of the instance methods that is declared in the subclass, I get an AttributeError: "subclass" Object has no attribute "non-extended method"

Is this some strange python inheritance rule that it is supposed to behave this way? And what am I supposed to do to be able to access the non-extended instance methods if I don't want those methods to be declared in the base class?

Thanks.

Comment: Updated strangeness. The code works perfectly fine on a friend's computer running the exact same code on the same version of python.

Comment: Can you add the minimum amount of code that reproduces the problem and specify your python version? (see the guidelines about asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)